# How can I cleanup my git repo and structure it properly without loosing any content

Tags: git, command-line

I came across a situation, where I already have a remote repository with master branch and some feature branch and have some of my commits pushed to remote as well, now locally also I have created some more branch but changes to these local branches are not pushed to remote.

Now due to some requirement, I need to restructure my repo and I need to keep my master clean with just readme and then move all the commits in master branch to another branch, as well as preserve my local commits and branches, so that I can push them after these clean-up.

I am not sure, How can I do this without loosing data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a "master backup" branch using

```
git checkout -b backupMaster
```

on your master branch.

You can delete the commit you want on master branch using

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard HEAD~x
```

X has to be the number of commit you want to delete.

Use

```
  git push origin master --force-with-lease
```

to update your origin/master with your local reseted master.

You master will now be clean in local and remote BUT if some unwanted commit you reverted on master are still present on other branch, you'll have to revert them on your other branches if you don't want bring them back on merge.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push